# Importing WMS from GeoServer to ArcGIS Online

Tags: geoserver, wms, arcgis-online

Can anybody give me step-by-step info for adding WMS from GeoServer to ArcGIS Online?

I tried many times but failed. I am able to add the same link on ArcMap but not in AGOL.

Comment: Please describe the exact steps you performed in at least one of your attempts, and include what happened at that attempt.

Comment: First I added the layer in geoserver later publish the layer. Then I tried to add WMS in AGOL with the following link: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms. This message came after trying to add layer - Service '' does not exist or is inaccessible. But this link is working on ArcMap and QGIS. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Is your service public